# Ajaxtool kit Tab Control Content controls outside of tab boundary

Tags: asp.net

Check out the first tab, the content for CARBS is nicely within the tab boundary, but for ISG, the  contents seems to be below a small rectangle which appears to be the tab boundary of the 2nd tab.

What am I doing wrong? It looks to me as though I did the 2nd tab teh same as the first where the ISG usercontrol is within teh 2nd TabPanel the way that the Carbs usercontrol is within the first tab panel....

Note that I removed the code for 3 of the tabs shown in the picture to simply the example.

content 
[image]

```
<%@ Page Title="Revenue Adjustment Ratios" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VerifyRevenueRatio.aspx.cs" Inherits="MLR_Datamart.VerifyRevenueRatio" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" %>
<%@ Register Src="Controls/Ratios_Carbs.ascx" TagName="Ratios_Carbs" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="Controls/Ratios_ISG.ascx" TagName="Ratios_ISG" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <link href="Styles/Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="9999999">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <ajaxtoolkit:TabContainer ID="tabDataEntry" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
        Width="1230px" ActiveTabIndex="1">
        <ajaxtoolkit:TabPanel ID="tabCarbs" runat="server" HeaderText="CARBS">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                CARBS</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc1:Ratios_Carbs ID="Ratios_Carbs1" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxtoolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxtoolkit:TabPanel ID="tabISG" runat="server" HeaderText="ISG">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                ISG</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc2:Ratios_ISG ID="Ratios_ISG1" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxtoolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxtoolkit:TabContainer>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely one of the User Controls' HTML is not well-formed, please check the HTML in control uc2:Ratios_ISG and its descendants, and see if all the HTML is properly closed.  One way to eye-ball the tag well-form-ness would be reformat the markup with Visual Studio, and you can quickly see if the indentation looks correct.

You may also temporarily mark the user control with     Visible="false", then add a few blank lines after the user control, and see if the same visual issue persists.  If so, you can be sure that the user control is the culprit.

Comment: Actually, the malformed tag was in the first (CARBS) user control, but your theory was on target.